# custom user profile pages

Tags: views, users, display-suite

I am working on a directory for a membership organization.

I am trying to create two distinct user pages. One for the user themselves (and admins) and one for the public to view. I would like these formatted differently, not just show different fields (which I could do simply with permissions, right?). And these public pages need to include Profile2 profile data.

I have tried editing the `user-profile.tpl.php` page. For example:

```
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print render($user_profile['field_first_name']); ?>
  <?php print render($user_profile['field_last_name']); ?>

</div>
```

...but this seems to have no effect on the user page at all, even when I clear all caches. (Perhaps because I'm using Display Suite to layout the user profile page? Does that override everything else?)

I also created a View:

- Contextual Filter

  - User:Uid
  - Provide default value: Type = User ID from URL
  - Specify validation criteria: Validator=User
- Relationship

  - User:Profile
  - Profile types (all 3 custom profile types chosen)
- Path: /users/%user

But I'm still just getting the Display Suite layout. Is that doing the override?

Answer (score 1):

DS uses it's own templates. Go to admin/config/people/accounts/display, then scroll to the bottom and DS will show you which templates you can use to overwrite the output.

In the example below there are 2 suggestions. Hope this helps you out.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. Thank you Robin. I have a couple questions, since I'm new to template stuff.

Comment: I found the "ds_2col.tpl.php" file and made a copy of it and renamed it "ds-2col--user.tpl.php".

1. Where does this file go? Leave it inside the display suite layouts folder or move it to my theme folder?

2. I looked at the file and can't figure out what I can do to edit it. It appears that there are two variables coming from somewhere else. The left column =  "<?php print $left; ?>", and the right column = "<?php print $right; ?>" Where is DS getting those variables "$left" and "$right"? Or am I looking in the wrong place to edit?

Comment: Also, once I edit the user profile template, any ideas how to have different formatting for the users and the public?